# How to get last installed/updated Jenkins plugins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My Jenkins instance interface broken. I suspect recent plugin update as the cause. However I cannot remember which plugins get updated recently. I need to know so I can rollback plugin version to the previous one.

How to find this information?

Some possible way:

- Jenkins log
- Retrieving plugins info via Groovy console

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In my opinion, the most efficient way is go to the `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins` directory, then issue command:

```
ls -alt *.hpi *.jpi
```

and the most recently update/installed plugins are ranking at the top of the results, hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Create a job scheduled to run daily, that logs the plugins and versions. There are several ways to do this, and it seems that none are straightforward or obvious. The method I've settled on simply archives the output file of this command:

```
curl -kLsS "${JENKINS_URL}pluginManager/api/json?pretty=1&tree=plugins\[shortName,longName,version\]" \
> plugin-list.txt
```

That give an easily accessible history from the Jenkins web UI. (Or on-disk if you know where to look.)
Diffs comparing previous version(s) left as an exercise for the reader.